# how to constrain a column value in MySQL based on other columns values?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, constraints

The following table stores phone numbers with the name of the person who uses that phone number:

```
CREATE TABLE phone_numbers (
    phone_number VARCHAR(12) PRIMARY KEY,
    name TINYTEXT,
    default_number BOOLEAN
);
```

People can have multiple phone numbers but only one of the phone numbers belonging to a person can be their default phone number (`deafault_number = 1`).

How would you write a constraint to enforce that each person can only have 1 default_number=1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a unique index.  In most databases, this would be a filtered unique index.  In MySQL it instead uses expressions:

```
create unique index unq_phone_numbers_name on
     phone_numbers(case when boolean then name end);
```

A unique index allows multiple `NULL` values.  But a given name can have only one number.

That said, I would actually suggest storing the default number in the `persons` table, where the name is stored.